# Oracle 11g select from three databases using two dblinks

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dblink

I have three databases **M,O,S**.
**M** has two DBLINKs to **O** and **S**.
I can select from **O** while connected to **M** like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1@O_DBLINK;
```

and also select from **S** while connected to **M** like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL2@S_DBLINK;
```

but when I try to select from both DBLINKs in a single script like this:

```
DECLARE
    a number;
    b number;
BEGIN
    SELECT colA into a FROM TBL1@O_DBLINK;
    SELECT colB into b FROM TBL2@S_DBLINK;
END;
```

it returns following error:

`ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object S.TBLB@S_DBLINK
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access`

**The very strange is that when I change the order of selects always the latter returns error:**

```
DECLARE
    a number;
    b number;
BEGIN
    SELECT colB into b FROM TBL2@S_DBLINK;
    SELECT colA into a FROM TBL1@O_DBLINK;
END;
```

`ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object O.TBLA@O_DBLINK
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access`

Comment: did you try - alter transaction read only; - before executing plsql block?

Comment: dear @0xdb : yes I used it (of course after I saw your  comment) but it did not change the error.

Comment: Is your remote db also on 11g or lower..?

Comment: @KaushikNayak: all of them are on 11g.

Comment: This thread https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9527327800346354051  could be of some help.

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I tried with two 11g and one 12c and it works.  Are you owner of the dblinks or public?

Comment: Try to run it in sqlplus, but before that, execute `rollback`, then `set transaction read only;`, followed by your anonymous procedure - see if it works like that.

Comment: The second "solution" I can provide you is: `DECLARE
    a number;
    b number;
BEGIN
    execute immediate 'SELECT colB into b FROM TBL2@S_DBLINK';
    execute immediate 'SELECT colA into a FROM TBL1@O_DBLINK';
END;` - I think that should work. If it doesn't work, try with `execute immediate 'SELECT colB FROM TBL2@S_DBLINK' into b; ` etc. - Can't test this one right now, but one of those should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach,

**Create table1 in Database M and create SYNONYM of that same table (table1) in remaining database O and S.**

Now you can do all manipulations.

for example:

```
create table table1 (col1); -- database M

create public synonym table1 for table1; -- database O & S
```

*Then now you can access the table with DB_Link and data will also reflected to all DB.*

> Refer the link to [CREATE SYNONYM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm)